# TimeDistributed Layer: Incompatible shapes: [32,3,3] vs. [32,3]

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, tf.keras

I have a model that was working before, but now it does not work. It gives an error about:

> InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [32,3,3] vs. [32,3]
>        [[{{node Nadam/gradients/loss/time_distributed_loss/SquaredDifference_grad/BroadcastGradientArgs}}]]

**The old model**:

```
class Model:
def set_the_model(self, look_back):
    self.model = Sequential()
    self.model.add(LSTM(16, activation="relu", input_shape=(look_back, 3),return_sequences=True)) #, stateful=True
    self.model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    self.model.add(LSTM(32, activation="relu", return_sequences=True))
    self.model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    self.model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(look_back)))
    #self.model.add(Dense(3))
    self.model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="nadam", metrics=['acc']) #mse
    self.model.summary()

def start_train(self, trainD1, trainD2):
    es = EarlyStopping(monitor='loss', patience = 2, mode='min')
    #for i, j in trainD1, trainD2:
    self.model.fit(trainD1, trainD2, epochs=200, batch_size = 32, verbose=1,  callbacks=[es])
    #  self.model.reset_states()

def predict_result(self, test_case):
    value = self.model.predict(test_case, verbose=0)
    return value
```

The error starts when I uncomment two lines of code in `start_train` method, and I turned the code into this (current model):

```
class Model:
def set_the_model(self, look_back):
    self.model = Sequential()
    self.model.add(LSTM(16, activation="relu", batch_input_shape=(1,look_back, 3),return_sequences=True, stateful=True))
    self.model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    self.model.add(LSTM(32, activation="relu", return_sequences=True))
    self.model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    self.model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(look_back)))
    #self.model.add(Dense(3))
    self.model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="nadam", metrics=['acc']) #mse
    self.model.summary()

def start_train(self, trainD1, trainD2):
    es = EarlyStopping(monitor='loss', patience = 2, mode='min')
    for i, j in zip(trainD1, trainD2):
        self.model.fit(i, j, epochs=200, batch_size = 1, verbose=1,  callbacks=[es])
        self.model.reset_states()

def predict_result(self, test_case):
    value = self.model.predict(test_case, verbose=0)
    return value
```

Then, I wanted to turn back to **old model**. When I started to train the model, It gives the error above.

This is how the model looks like:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm (LSTM)                  (None, 3, 16)             1280      
_________________________________________________________________ 
dropout (Dropout)            (None, 3, 16)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_1 (LSTM)                (None, 3, 32)             6272      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 3, 32)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed (TimeDistri (None, 3, 3)              99        
=================================================================
Total params: 7,651
Trainable params: 7,651
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Edit: I changed `batch_size` into 1 on the old model, and now it works, but now, It will be extremely slow.

Comment: What is the purpose of looping through every observation in dataset? As I understand correctly, it is exactly what for i, j in zip(trainD1, trainD2) is doing. So it is why your code is working on batch_size = 1 and does not work on higher batch_size values.

Comment: @s3nh The `old model' works with a single dataset. The second model works with multiple inputs, and It would not be good (according to my data) if I combine the inputs. Every input that I worked with does not have the same input size; therefore, cannot be divided by 32. If I do not send as a one, It gives me an error